# Find Latin/Greek Word Roots NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

Is there a way I could find the Latin root/definition of said root in a word with NLTK (and possibly wordnet)?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are [lemmatizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation). A Latin lemmatizer is:

- LemLat [for [one word](http://www.ilc.cnr.it/lemlat/), whole [text document]](http://www.ilc.cnr.it/lemlat/)

A Greek lemmatizer:

- The [Grammatical Tagger](http://hermes.di.uoa.gr/gramtaggereng.htm) by ELTL [[download](http://hermis.di.uoa.gr:8080/gramtag/indexeng.html)]

Comment: This post used to have 3 upvotes; recently it got 2 downvotes within an hour (after years of inactivity). Can the downvote people please explain their problem with this answer?